# postgresql: no such file or directory, using ssh, cpanel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, cpanel

i am using windows 7 and putty for access ssh of my hosting (cPanel).

using this guide: https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/installing-postgresql-howto.13474/

i checked my cpanel and whm and didn't find any thing named postgre / postgresql, so i tried through ssh command line.

but when i type this command

```
myuser@host [~]# /scripts/installpostgres
-bash: /scripts/installpostgres: No such file or directory
```

well in the link it says login to a root shell but i am login with my cpanel id, may be that step is making a cause!

thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry no one is going to read a document just to help you figure this out. Either post the relevent bits or better, contact your hosting companies support;

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not logged in your server with the root user. Please login your cPanel server with the root user and try with same command.